# Are there re-open review tests?

Tags: support, review, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

ServerFault doesn't generate very many re-open reviews, today when I looked it showed there was one question to be reviewed.  Even though the counter only showed one, after I dealt with that, I was shown this question:

[Load avg weirdness on Linux Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/463359/load-avg-weirdness-on-linux-ubuntu)

I clicked through to get a better sense of what the question was, and found it *wasn't* closed, didn't even have any close votes.  The question seemed fine to me, so I selected "Re-open", got the usual dialog box "Nominate this question for re-opening?" and when I was done it showed I'd done two reviews today.

I thought review tests had some sort of dialog afterward to tell you what just happened, but there was no message about this being a test, it behaved just like a regular review.

So was this a glitch?

Comment: [This question doesn't seem to have ever been closed.](http://serverfault.com/posts/463359/revisions)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are. Not all the queues actually display a notice when you pass an audit, but the [review item itself](https://serverfault.com/review/reopen/53049) will list that you passed the audit.

> [image: Reopen Votes Audit Passed]

Comment: That makes sense, although it doesn't make sense that the audits don't always tell you what just happened.  And I have no idea how to get back to the page you got the screenshot from, unless you're in the process of reviewing and go back.

Comment: You can always find all the reviews you've ever done listed in your activity under the reviews tab. Just lick on the action part in the listing (in this case Reopen). They're also listed under the history tab in the review panel, but that will include other users' reviews as well if you have 10k privileges.

Comment: The re-open votes are a lot trickier than edit reviews; I missed one because I felt that the question, while allegedly closed as "Not A Real Question", deserved to stay closed as "Too Localized".  Apparently, "Leave Closed" was the wrong answer, and now I know.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: That's the problem with Close/Reopen queues. Those votes, by nature, are *highly* subjective. It's very, very difficult to create automated audits. They really should use questions which have been closed *and* deleted. Being deleted is like a final confirmation that the community felt the question was bad. But even then, it can still be fairly subjective.